# ModelState.AddModelError - no error shown

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, modelstate

I'd like to set an error message for an email field after an exception has been caught in my controller:

```
...
catch (EmailAlreadyExistsException emailAlreadyExistsException)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("Useraccount_Email", "This is an error message");

    RegisterViewModel viewModel = new RegisterViewModel
    {
        Useraccount = useraccount,
        InformationMessages = InformationMessageHelper.GetInformationMessages()
    };
    return PartialView(viewModel);
}
...
```

The error message should now be displayed in my view:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Register", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "registerAjaxSuccess" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)        
    <div class="ym-grid">
        <div class="ym-g33 ym-gl">
            <div class="ym-gbox">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Useraccount.LastName)
            </div>
...
    <div class="ym-grid">
        <div class="ym-g33 ym-gl">
            <div class="ym-gbox">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Useraccount.Email)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ym-g33 ym-gl">
            <div class="ym-gbox">                  
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Useraccount.Email, new { required = "required" })                 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ym-g33 ym-gr">
            <div class="ym-gbox">
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Useraccount.Email)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
...
```

But nothing is shown in this case. :(
What did I do wrong?

Comment: Where is the `Html.ValidationSummary(true)` in your view?

Comment: It's there, see updated source code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When adding model errors the correct separator when working with complex objects is the dot `.` and not the unserscore `_`

So the following call should work:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Useraccount.Email", "This is an error message");
```

Comment: Thank you sir. This did the trick.
Is there any possibility to avoid a hardcoded string for the key and access the information from the model itself?

Answer (score 0):

Please use ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "This is an error message");
and  @Html.ValidationSummary(true);

This will work.