# How to add a ModelState error for an object inside a model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have the following models:

```
class Identity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

class Person
{
    public Identity Identity { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to add a validation model error to the surname in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreatePerson(Person person)
{
   // some validation stuff
   ModelState.AddModelError("Identity.Surname", "Surname has not been found in BBDD");
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

How must I refer to the surname inside the `Identity` object to show the validation error correctly in my view?

I show the validation error in the view as:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Identity.Surname)
```

But the error is shown in the general validation summary.

Comment: Whats the name of the property in class `Person` - `public Identity WhatName { get; set; }`!

Comment: Sorry, It was mispelled, updated.

Comment: Then `ModelState.AddModelError("Identity.Surname", "...)` is correct - assuming you view has `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Identity.Surname)`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Mmmm I see, it's not really working, I don't know why

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504348/modelstate-addmodelerror-no-error-shown

Comment: Must be another issue. As a side note, if you want client side validation for this property as well you can look at using a `[Remote]` attribute

Comment: I assume you are calling `return View(person);` after adding the `ModelState` error

Comment: Check in the view the parameter is `true`  for `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)`

Answer (score 1):

you can try to implement `Remote` attribute to your Surname property. It will allow you to perform validation on client side using ajax to check whatever you want on server. Here is [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx).

```
class Identity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Remote("CheckSurname", "Validation")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

public class ValidationController : Controller {

    public JsonResult CheckSurname(string Surname) {

        if(/*your busines logic*/) {
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else {
            return Json("Your error message here", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        } 

    }
}
```

in web.config you should enable this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Nice suggestion, but **not an answer** to the question

Comment: @StephenMuecke just another way to do ops task. He wants error page? He can get it without posting a form.

Comment: It does not answer OP's question which is _how to add a ModelState error in the controller_